# Transfer Source Destination Search

Tags: jackhenry-jxchange

When making the request, we get returned a field "RstrExcType" and are uncertain how to handle this field. We don't see it but twice in documentation. Two values we see are "Cls" and "LmtTrn". How should this field be handled and what values are expected?

```
    <XferSrcDestRstrArray>
    <XferSrcDestRstrInfo>
    <XferSrcDestType>Both</XferSrcDestType>
    <RstrExcType>Cls</RstrExcType>
    <Ver_1></Ver_1>
    </XferSrcDestRstrInfo>
    </XferSrcDestRstrArray>
```

We performed a request using http://jackhenry.com/ws/XferSrcDestSrch in the DMZ and reviewed the results against the documentation.

While we did see the XferSrcDestSrchRq_MType list of exclusions, **LmtTrn** was missing from the documentation and we were not certain if anything else was as well.

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found this information on the message brief for the API here: https://jackhenry.dev/open-enterprise-api-docs/enterprise-soap-api/api-reference/core-services/xfersrcdestsrch/

We recommend further research at that link for documentation requested as well as full information about the API, example XML, mappings and errors.

Here are the restrictions mentioned within the message brief.

"The XferSrcDestSrchRq_MType message permits a consumer to submit an array of restrictions to be considered by the Service Provider to exclude qualifying accounts from the response set. The RstrExcType element is a closed enumerated element with the following canonical values:

Limited Transaction: ~LmtTrn~
Charged Off: ~ChgdOff~
Closed: ~Cls~
Dormant: ~Dormant~
No Post: ~NoPost~
Restriction on Transactions: ~RstrTrn~
Escheat: ~Escheat~
Frozen: ~Frz~
No Credits Posting: ~NoCr~"

Comment: Thank you, we didn't see LmtTrn in the listing. Appreciate the pointer!